# Catching calls from a program in runtime and mapping them to other calls

Tags: c++, c, linux, theory

A program usually depends on several libraries and might sometimes depend on other programs as well.  I look at projects like Wine and think how do they figure out what calls a program is making?

In a Linux environment, what are the approaches used to know what calls an executable is making in runtime in order to catch and map them to other calls?

Any code snippets or references to resources for extra reading is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you mean how to statically document the calls in a source code file or to do something in runtime, both are not languaje-agnostic, but specially the second is very dependent on the technology used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually meant in runtime. What I'm interested in is the approach, the language agnostic tag was just there so that anybody can put some code sample in any language if they want to clarify a point. Just edited the question and post.

Comment: check the strace command in linux. It will list all the calls a executable / command will be making . Hope this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about how WINE works. It doesn't catch system calls and re-route them to it's own versions. I'm no expert on WINE, but I believe it instead sets up a full Windows environment in which to run the executable. When calling code in a DLL, the real actual Windows DLL is loaded in the usual manner and executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you're looking for the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. This will load your libraries before any requested by the program. If you provide a function definition that matches one loaded by the target program then your version will be called instead.

You can't really detect what functions a program is calling however. You can however get all the functions in a shared library and implement all of those. You aren't really *catching* the functions, you are simply reimplementing them.

Projects like Wine do this in some cases, but not in all. They also rewrite some of the dynamic libraries. So when a Win32 loads some DLL it is actually loading the Wine version and not the native version. This is essentially the same concept of replacing the functions with your own.

Lookup LD_PRELOAD for more information.